# Помогите разобраться с синтаксисом компонента Vue написанного на TypeScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, компоненты

**UPDATE** См. конце в вопроса

Ни когда не использовал TypeScript. Но понадобилось покопаться внутри компонента Vue, который реализован на TypeScript. Может быть этот синтаксис аналогичен и для JavaScript, я не знаю. Но мне неочень понятны некоторые строки.

Сначала размещу весь код компонента, это компонент Vue-Tabulator, непонятные строки пометил комментариями, а дальше написал вопросы по ним:

```
<script lang='ts'>
import {
  Component, Prop, Vue, Watch, Model,
} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { IntegrationOptions, UpdateStrategy } from '@/types';
import mergeWith from 'lodash.mergewith'
import merge from '../utilities/merge'
const Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables');
import eventFactory from '../feature/event-factory'
import cellEvents from '../feature/events/cell-events'
import rowEvents from '../feature/events/row-events'

@Component({
  name: 'TabulatorComponent',
})
export default class TabulatorComponent extends Vue {
  @Model('change', { default: () => [] })
  public tableData?: Array<any>;

  //1--------------
  private tabulatorInstance: Tabulator | null = null; 

  get eventOptions(): Object {
    const events = eventFactory.bind(this)
    return {...events(rowEvents), ...events(cellEvents)}
  }

  //2--------------
  @Prop({ default: () => ({}) })
  private options?: Tabulator.Options; 

  //3--------------
  @Prop({ default: () => ({ updateStrategy: UpdateStrategy.DATA }) })
  private integration?: IntegrationOptions;

  //4--------------
  private resolvedOptions: Tabulator.Options = {}; 

  public getInstance() {
    return this.tabulatorInstance;
  }

  private createTable() {
    this.tabulatorInstance = new Tabulator(
      this.$refs.table,
      this.resolvedOptions,
    );
  }

  @Watch('options', { deep: true })
  private updateOptions() {

    this.resolvedOptions = {
      ...mergeWith(this.eventOptions, this.options, merge),
      data: this.tableData,
    };

    this.createTable();
  }

  @Watch('tableData', { deep: true })
  private updateData() {
    //5--------------
    if (this.tabulatorInstance) { 
      if (this.integration && this.integration.updateStrategy === UpdateStrategy.REPLACE) {
        this.tabulatorInstance.replaceData(this.tableData);
      } else if (this.integration && this.tableData
      && this.integration.updateStrategy === UpdateStrategy.UPDATE) {
        this.tabulatorInstance.updateData(this.tableData);
      } else {
        this.tabulatorInstance.setData(this.tableData);
      }
    }
  }

  mounted() {
    this.updateOptions();
  }
}
```

Строки по каким возникли вопросы:

1. `private tabulatorInstance: Tabulator | null = null; //1`

Что значит вcе что после двоеточия?

поле tabulatorInstance может принимать тип Tabulator или null? Что за странная конструкция `| null = null`

2. `private options?: Tabulator.Options; //2`
   Что значит оператор `?:`
3. `private integration?: IntegrationOptions; //3`
   Здесь я знаю что IntegrationOptions это enum из другого файла

Чтов этом случае значит это объявление?

4. `private resolvedOptions: Tabulator.Options = {}; //4`
   Похоже на 2, но почему то тут появилось `= {}`
5. `if (this.tabulatorInstance) { //5`

Как tabulatorInstance может оказаться незаполненным?

**UPDATE:**

В компоненте есть еще такой файл entry.ts. Точка входа для компонента. Я как понял, эта точка входа необходима для компонента, который будет подключаться как плагин к приложению, т.е. через Vue.use().

Понял из этого, все кроме последнего блока кода для чего принудительно вызывается функция install? Это так принято или это решение разработчика так реализовать?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import TabulatorComponent from '@/components/TabulatorComponent.vue';

export { TabulatorComponent };

function install(VueApp: typeof Vue, options: any = {}) {
  const name = options.name || 'VueTabulator';
  VueApp.component(name, TabulatorComponent);
}; 

export default {
  install,
};

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && (<any>window).Vue && (<any>window).Vue === Vue) {
  install((<any>window).Vue)
}
```

Comment: 1: выставляем для `tabulatorInstance` тип `Tabulator` или null и присваиваем значение null.
2: необязательность

Comment: 4. `{}` - пустой объект. 5. Эм, так как изначально ему и присвоено значение `null`

Comment: Kir_Antipov, я просто подумал, что после монтирования tabulatorInstance будет определен и не пойму, как может сработать watch на tableData до того, как будет смонтирован сам компонент

Comment: Или скорей всего это просто перестраховка разработчика, так как null присваивается, мало ли где вылезет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> private tabulatorInstance: Tabulator | null = null; //1 Что значит вcе
>   что после двоеточия?
>
> поле tabulatorInstance может принимать тип Tabulator или null? Что за
>   странная конструкция | null = null

Смотрите, всё что стоит после `:` - это объявление типа. Всё что стоит после `=` - это объявление значение.  `|` в объявлении типа - это `или`.

То есть в этом случае мы сообщаем компилятору: поле `tabulatorInstance` может быть типа `Tabulator` или `null`. И после `=` мы сообщаем JS-интерпретатору - присвоить значение `null`. После компиляции чистый JS будет таким: `tabulatorInstance = null`.

> private options?: Tabulator.Options; //2 Что значит оператор ?:

`?` перед объявлением типа означает то что это поле опционально и может быть `undefined`.  Эту запись можно переписать как `private options: Tabulator.Options | undefined`.

> private integration?: IntegrationOptions; //3 Здесь я знаю что
>   IntegrationOptions это enum из другого файла

> Что в этом случае значит это объявление?
>
> private resolvedOptions: Tabulator.Options = {}; //4 Похоже на 2, но
>   почему то тут появилось = {}

Это означает "присвоить значение `{}`". Как и в обыкновенном JS.

> if (this.tabulatorInstance) { //5
>
> Как tabulatorInstance может оказаться незаполненным?

`tabulatorInstance` может принять значение `null`. Тут мы это как раз и проверяем.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! если вас не затруднит можете еще прокомментировать файл точки входа, я в текст вопроса добавил UPDATE. Я там написал, какой момент не понятен.

Comment: Во вью не разбираюсь, но вот как экспортировать компоненты правильно: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html#What-does-my-packaged-component-look-like. Так что можно сказать что автор вашего плагина от себя ничего не добавил. Кроме, разве что, вызова `install` напрямую вместо `window.Vue.use({install})` как это делают в документации.